# Save NSmutableArray to file and load

Tags: objective-c, serialization, nsmutablearray

i am written app for my iphone and i want to save some NSmutablearray to file 
and load it later. i read about NSArchiver but didnt understand how to work with
my calss is :

```
@interface Shop : NSObject 
{    
    NSString       *m_Name;
    NSString       *m_Description;
    NSString       *m_Category;
    NSString       *m_BestSaleDesc;
    NSString       *m_AdditionalInfo;   
    NSInteger       m_ShopId;
    NSInteger       m_ChainId;
    NSMutableArray *m_SalesList;
    NSData         *m_Icon;
    bool            m_Filtered;
    bool            m_Deleted;
    bool            m_Hidden;
}
```

can someone give me example code of how to save an NSmutableArray of calss Shop to file name ShopFile.sav  and then how to load it again to NSmutableArray object.
thanks so much

Comment: Hey, I rewrote my entire code below. If you haven't already figured this out, then take a look.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Redid the entire thing.
Saving:

```
NSMutableDictionary *saveDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[saveDict setValue:m_Name forKey:@"m_Name"];
[saveDict setValue:m_Description forKey:@"m_Description"];
[saveDict setValue:m_Category forKey:@"m_Category"];
[saveDict setValue:m_BestSaleDesc forKey:@"m_BestSaleDesc"];
[saveDict setValue:m_AdditionalInfo forKey:@"m_AdditionalInfo"];
[saveDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:m_ShopId] forKey:@"m_ShopId"];
[saveDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:m_ChainId] forKey:@"m_ChainId"];
[saveDict setValue:m_SalesList forKey:@"m_SalesList"];
[saveDict setValue:m_Icon forKey:@"m_Icon"];
[saveDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:m_Filtered] forKey:@"m_Filtered"];
[saveDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:m_Deleted] forKey:@"m_Deleted"];
[saveDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:m_Hidden] forKey:@"m_Hidden"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/ShopFile.sav"];
[saveDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Loading:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/ShopFile.sav"];
NSDictionary *loadDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
m_Name =            [loadDict valueForKey:@"m_Name"];
m_Description =     [loadDict valueForKey:@"m_Description"];
m_Category =        [loadDict valueForKey:@"m_Category"];
m_BestSaleDesc =    [loadDict valueForKey:@"m_BestSaleDesc"];
m_AdditionalInfo =  [loadDict valueForKey:@"m_AdditionalInfo"];
m_ShopId =         [[loadDict valueForKey:@"m_ShopId"] intValue];
m_ChainID =        [[loadDict valueForKey:@"m_ChainId"] intValue];
m_SalesList =       [loadDict valueForKey:@"m_SalesList"];
m_Icon =            [loadDict valueForKey:@"m_Icon"];
m_Filtered =       [[loadDict valueForKey:@"m_Filtered"] boolValue];
m_Deleted =        [[loadDict valueForKey:@"m_Deleted"] boolValue];
m_Hidden =         [[loadDict valueForKey:@"m_Hidden"] boolValue];
```

Should work better ;)

Comment: its look like good example but i didnt see anywhere in the code where i save NSmutablearray of shops???  
I only see NSArray *save = m_SalesList;

Comment: "Save" is a copy of your array, and then "save" is written to the file "Shopfile.sav" in the app's Documents directory. You could use [m_SalesList writeToFile: atomically:], but this is my method ;)

This assumes that your array is already set up. If you want to create your array, that's a different question.

Comment: but as you can see m_SalesList is not my Shop list its just a member in the Shop class that represent another list of somthing.
i want to save list of Shops (m_ShopList) that every member of this list contain the members of class Shop(you can see is the top of the page) and one of those members is SalesList.
you think that [m_ShopList writeToFile: atomically:] will do the job?
i dont need to archive or serialize the list?

many thanks

Comment: [m_ShopList writeToFile:atomically:] should work, unless I am misinterpreting what you said. Try testing it, and if it doesn't work, I'll keep thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Core Data? [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)